# PHP multiline input from shell_exec not woking as expected

Tags: php, shell-exec

I have the following PHP post from HTML

The output from the `mvsce -d 1234-56-78 -l 1 -s 1` command is displayed from bash as follows

```
TAR 332 
PCXLA-TAACC
```

over the two lines.

The code below only ever outputs the 2nd line `PCXLA-TAACC`

```
<?php
$mvdate=$_POST['fdate'];
$mvlevel=$_POST['flevel'];
$mvsite=$_POST['fsite'];

$mvse = shell_exec ('/usr/local/bin/mvsce -d "'.$mvdate.'" -l "'.$mvlevel.'" -s "'.$mvsite.'"');

echo $mvse;

?>
```

---

**How can I get the code to display both lines in a browser windows?**

---

The HTML I use to post for the PHP

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<H1>makeVSCE Output</H1><br>
<br>
<br>
<form name="myForm" action="makevsce.php"
method="post">
Date (YYYY-MM-DD):<br>
<input TYPE="text" NAME="fdate"><br>
Level:<br>
<input TYPE="level" NAME="flevel"><br>
Sequence:<br>
<input TYPE="Sequence" NAME="fsite">

<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<br>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you run the same command (minus any $_POST variables)  as your not running the same thing (you have quotes in your `shell_exec()` call for example.

Comment: SO I have substitude the variables in the command to actual figures. running the php from command line reports both lines to console. Run the PHP from a browser and only the 2nd line is displayed

Comment: All I'm saying is try the exact command you tried from the command line - cut and paste it into your script.

Comment: I did that run the php from console it displays both lines as expected. running from a browser only the 2nd line is displayed.

Comment: Then it is an issue with the browser's page rendering. You are rendering a valid HTML page with at least `<html>` [...] `</html>` tags and a **body**. Do you?. Btw: I edited my answer. Still you need to render a proper html page.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I get the code to display both lines in a browser window?

**Short answer: You have to render a minimal HTML page and format output according to HTML.**

---

Let your script `makevsce.php` begin sending the client **a minimal HTML page with the body "*open*"**:

```
<?php
header( "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8" );

echo "<!DOCTYPE html>\n";
echo "<html>\n";
echo "<head>\n";
echo "<meta charset=\"utf-8\">\n";
echo "<title>Shell Output (or whatever...)</title>\n";
echo "</head>\n";
echo "<body>\n";
```

---

**Let PHP properly escape the arguments** injected in the string passed to the shell.

```
$mvdate  = escapeshellarg( $_POST['fdate'] );
$mvlevel = escapeshellarg( $_POST['flevel']);
$mvsite  = escapeshellarg( $_POST['fsite'] );
```

---

Use **[`exec`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)** instead of `shell_exec`

```
exec( "/usr/local/bin/mvsce -d $mvdate -l $mvlevel -s $mvsite",
      $mvse,
      $return_value );
```

`$mvse` (passed by reference) will receive an array containing all the lines sent as output from the invoked command.

While the (optional) parameter `$return_value` holds the return value of the shell command.

---

**To display the output:**

```
foreach( $mvse as $line ) {
    echo htmlspecialchars( $line ) . "<br>\n";
```

Note that prior printing each output line text is properly HTML escaped since you're talking about displaying output in a browser.

At the end of each line a `<br>` will be interpreted by the browser as a line break.

---

Finally to close the HTML page:

```
echo "</body>\n";
echo "</html>";
```

---

**Security notice:**

Be aware you're executing via the shell a command created using input from the **client**.

A properly forged request may cause execution of arbitrary command with the same privileges as the PHP runtime.

Comment: Still only reports the 2nd line, I have amended the question to truly reflect the bash output.

Comment: @JustinCooper-Marsh made several additions to my answer. Give it a look...

Answer (score 0):

OK,

This is not an issue with PHP code.

If I write the output from the command to anything other than console it only writes the 2nd line.

Thanks for all your help.

Comment: This doesn't make much sense. Maybe the command is sending some output (the first line) to `stderr`. Try adding `2>&1` at the end of the command (the one issued from PHP)

Comment: `/usr/local/bin/mvsce -d $mvdate -l $mvlevel -s $mvsite 2>&1`